# Cassandra 4 - java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread

Tags: cassandra

After upgrading Cassandra 3.x to 4.X follows error occurs.

```
INFO  [NonPeriodicTasks:1] 2022-09-24T04:41:26,003 SSTable.java:111 - Deleting sstable: XXX/cassandra/data/system/compaction_history-b4dbb7b4dc493fb5b3bfce6e434832ca/nb-152737-big
INFO  [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,023 ColumnFamilyStore.java:878 - Enqueuing flush of in_production_checks: 21.660KiB (0%) on-heap, 0.000KiB (0%) off-heap
INFO  [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,024 ColumnFamilyStore.java:878 - Enqueuing flush of ingestion_hosts_v3: 323.955KiB (0%) on-heap, 0.000KiB (0%) off-heap
INFO  [COMMIT-LOG-ALLOCATOR] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,025 ColumnFamilyStore.java:878 - Enqueuing flush of spock_cluster_leases: 2.563KiB (0%) on-heap, 0.000KiB (0%) off-heap
INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:940] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,081 Memtable.java:471 - Writing Memtable-in_production_checks@1168154357(6.122KiB serialized bytes, 25 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit), flushed range = (min(-9223372036854775808), max(9223372036854775807)]
INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:940] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,082 Memtable.java:500 - Completed flushing XXX/cassandra/data/keyspace1/in_production_checks-7810e5c0922511ea9d87c1aca011cf3c/nb-182421-big-Data.db (3.813KiB) for commitlog position CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1663918207131, position=25214)
INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:941] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,086 Memtable.java:471 - Writing Memtable-ingestion_hosts_v3@1316569071(58.113KiB serialized bytes, 5831 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit), flushed range = (min(-9223372036854775808), max(9223372036854775807)]
INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:941] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,091 Memtable.java:500 - Completed flushing XXX/cassandra/data/keyspace1/ingestion_hosts_v3-762f7b90922511ea9d87c1aca011cf3c/nb-399812-big-Data.db (44.660KiB) for commitlog position CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1663918207131, position=25214)
INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:940] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,218 Memtable.java:471 - Writing Memtable-spock_cluster_leases@1265068081(0.164KiB serialized bytes, 78 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit), flushed range = (min(-9223372036854775808), max(9223372036854775807)]
INFO  [PerDiskMemtableFlushWriter_0:940] 2022-09-24T04:44:49,218 Memtable.java:500 - Completed flushing XXX/cassandra/data/keyspace2/tbl1-78b6e9c0922511ea9d87c1aca011cf3c/nb-278783-big-Data.db (0.135KiB) for commitlog position CommitLogPosition(segmentId=1663918207131, position=25214)
ERROR [GossipTasks:1] 2022-09-24T04:45:11,989 DefaultPromise.java:844 - Failed to submit a listener notification task. Event loop shut down?
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
        at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:719) ~[?:1.8.0_345]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor.startThread(GlobalEventExecutor.java:232) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.GlobalEventExecutor.execute(GlobalEventExecutor.java:208) ~[netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.safeExecute(DefaultPromise.java:842) [netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenerWithStackOverFlowProtection(DefaultPromise.java:529) [netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener(DefaultPromise.java:477) [netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.CompleteFuture.addListener(CompleteFuture.java:48) [netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.FutureCombiner.<init>(FutureCombiner.java:83) [apache-cassandra-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.FutureCombiner.<init>(FutureCombiner.java:55) [apache-cassandra-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.InboundSockets.open(InboundSockets.java:235) [apache-cassandra-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.MessagingService.waitUntilListening(MessagingService.java:534) [apache-cassandra-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.gms.Gossiper$GossipTask.run(Gossiper.java:287) [apache-cassandra-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
        at org.apache.cassandra.concurrent.DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$UncomplainingRunnable.run(DebuggableScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:118) [apache-cassandra-4.0.5.jar:4.0.5]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308) [?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) [?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294) [?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_345]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_345]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) [netty-all-4.1.58.Final.jar:4.1.58.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) [?:1.8.0_345]
```

I'm using old java client(cassandra-driver-core-3.9.0) with Cassandra 4.x.
Frequency of the error not so often. It generally happens rarely than 6 hours.

*Setup information.*

```
# ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 63939
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 100000
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 63939
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Cassandra is running with `-Xss256k -Xms4020M -Xmx4020M -Xmn1005M` . On Cassandra 3.x it was fine.

```
# java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_345"
```

Answer (score 2):

In the information you provided, there isn't anything obvious that points to a problem other than the JVM running out of memory. This situation happens when lots of threads get created.

You will need to do a thread dump with tools like `jstack` and analyse the output for clues. Things that you would be looking for are:

- what threads are being created
- top threads (by count)

If you haven't done a thread dump analysis before, you'll need to do some research to get an idea of what's required. Be aware that the analysis is more an art rather than science.

A temporary workaround is to increase the heap to at least 8GB for very low production workloads. Cheers!

Comment: It turned out that issues caused by other processed which triggering huge number of threads. Cassandra is fine.
For my case the solution is to play with OS kernel configurations. maximum PID number has been changed.